Connective covers of based spaces
I know that n-connective spectra form a coreflective subcategory of spectra. Namely, there is a n-connective cover functor $\tau_{>k}: Spectra\rightarrow Spectra^{n-connective}$ which has a fully faithful left adjoint. In particular, the counit gives a natural morphism $\tau_{>k}(E)\rightarrow E$ for each spectrum $E$.
I am wondering if the same holds unstably, for based spaces. Namely, I suspect that based n-connected spaces for a coreflective subcategory of based spaces $Space^*$, i.e. there is a n-connected cover functor $\tau_{>k}: Space^*\rightarrow Space^{*, n-connected}$ with a fully faithful left adjoint. I think the functor $\tau_{>n}$ can be obtained by taking the homotopy fiber of the unit $X \rightarrow \tau_{\le n} X$, where $\tau_{\le n}$ is the truncation functor $\tau_{\le n}: Space\rightarrow Space^{n-truncated}$, which is a localization. Is there a reference for this? (if it is true). I am specifically asking about the unstable case, as opposed to references for the case of spectra, which seems well-known. One potential issue I can foresee is that $\tau_{>n}$ may not be $n$-connected.
Note that to take the homotopy fiber functorially, we need to work with based spaces. Another reason that we need to work with based spaces is that unbased n-connected spaces do not have all colimits (for example, they do not have an initial object - see the discussion here Is there a homotopy theory of unbased simply connected spaces?).
On the other hand, (an accessible) coreflective  localization of a presentable category $Space^*$ would also be presentable and hence have all colimits.

There's a theorem in "Elements of homotopy theory" by G. W. Whitehead, where connective cover functors are constructed (chapter on Postnikov systems, page 425). The language used in the book doesn't make it obvious that constructions are natural before passing to homotopy category, but they are; you just need to choose a good model for Hurewitz homomorphism (namely, the colimit of infinite symmetric powers of n-truncations).

Such a tower is usually called a Whitehead tower. More generally, there is the notion of a Moore-Postnikov factorization of a map $f: X \to Y$ of spaces: fixing an $n$, we can find a factorization $X \to M_n(f) \to Y$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi_k(X) \xrightarrow{\sim} \pi_k(M_n f)&\text{ for }k < n,\\
\pi_k(X) \twoheadrightarrow \pi_k(M_n f) \hookrightarrow \pi_k(Y)&\text{ for }k=n,\\
\pi_k(M_n f) \xrightarrow{\sim} \pi_k(Y)&\text{ for }k > n.
\end{align*}
$$
The Postnikov tower of $X$ is made up of Moore-Postnikov factorizations of $X \to \ast$, and the Whitehead tower of a pointed space $Y$ is made up of Moore-Postnikov factorizations of $\ast \to Y$. We can form $M_n f$ by attaching cells to $X$ of dimension at least $n+1$ to kill off the relative homotopy groups $\pi_k(f)$.
Moore gives a construction via simplicial sets in the paper "Semi-simplicial complexes and Postnikov systems". You can see this described in a way that is more explicitly functorial in May's "Simplicial objects in algebraic topology" (which I got from this answer).
